# Why do I have to click twice to execute method in Label MouseDown event

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, multithreading

I'm working on an assignment for College and the requirements are that I have to use multi-threading, now everytime I login, I have to click twice to change the UI for the MainWindow. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

If I use the code from the `user_login` method it works fine, UI updates quickly, but when I use multi-threading I have to click the label twice in order to change my UI.

I've done the same using a button control but also has the same result for both tests given above.

```
        private void tbLogin_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //Assign Class Property Values
            login.Student_Email = txtstd_Email.Text;
            login.Student_Password = txtstd_Password.Password;

            Thread user_login_thread = new Thread(() => User_Login(login.Student_Email, 
                                                                   login.Student_Password));
            user_login_thread.Start();

            if (login.UserLoggedIn)
            {
                foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
                {
                    if (window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
                    {
                        //Change page on login           
                        (window as MainWindow).frmView.Source = new Uri("Views/Dashboard.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
                    }
                }
            }

            user_login_thread.Join();

            if (chkRemember.IsChecked == true)
            {
                Properties.Settings.Default.Student_Email = login.Student_Email;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Student_Password = login.Student_Password;
                Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            }

        }
```

```
private void User_Login(string email, string password)
{
    //Security object
    Secure security = new Secure();

    conn.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT Student_Number, Student_FullName, Student_Email, Student_Password FROM 
                 Student_Data WHERE Student_Email=@Email";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = password;

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read() && 
           login.Student_Password.Equals(security.Decrypt(reader["Student_Password"].ToString())))
        {

            login.UserLoggedIn = true;
        }
        else
        {
           _ = MessageBox.Show("Login Unsuccessful", "Student Login Unsuccessfull", 
                               MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: *I have to use multi-threading* - can you please post the exact wording in your assignment that creates this restriction?

Comment: ```Regardless of database access technology, the application should use multi-threading to
ensure that the user interface never becomes unresponsive while retrieving or storing
information.```

Comment: Multithreading does not strictly mean to create a new Thread explicitly. `Task.Run` would use a thread from a thread pool.

Comment: IMHO the relevant part of that requirement is 'ensure that the user interface never becomes unresponsive while retrieving or storing information'. If you achieve this by an explicit new thread or by asynchronous programing, should be irrelevant. Unless this is a homework requiring explicitly the creation of new threads, the answer of Charlieface is perfectly fine.

Comment: Its part of this semester grade and I got marks deducted because my lecturer didn't know how a delegate works so just being cautious

Comment: @PureWare-LegendsOfGaming OK, I would then also use threads :D

Answer (score 2):

The primary issue is that you are not waiting for the query to finsih before checking `if (login.UserLoggedIn)`.

I'd advise you to use `async` and `await` for this instead of threading.

You have some other issues also:

- connection and reader objects need `using` blocks.
- Do *not* cache the connection, create a new one when you need it.
- Reversible encryption on a password is a bad idea, use hashing instead. Pass the hash to the server for it to verify, don't bring it back to the client app.
- Don't block the thread with message boxes while the connection is open.
- Don't read more columns than you need.
- If you only have one column and row use ExecuteScalar

```cs
private async void tbLogin_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //Assign Class Property Values
    login.Student_Email = txtstd_Email.Text;
    login.Student_Password = txtstd_Password.Password;

    await User_Login(login.Student_Email, login.Student_Password));

    .....


private async Task User_Login(string email, string password)
{
    //Security object
    Secure security = new Secure();

    const string sql = @"
SELECT 1
FROM Student_Data
WHERE Student_Email = @Email
  AND Student_Password = @Pass;
";

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(yourConnString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = email;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", SqlDbType.VarChar, 55).Value = security.Encrypt(password);
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        login.UserLoggedIn = await comm.ExecuteScalarAsync() != null;
    }
    if (!login.UserLoggedIn)
    {
       _ = MessageBox.Show("Login Unsuccessful", "Student Login Unsuccessfull", 
                           MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: The requirements state multi-threading not asynchronous

Comment: Given that you are just doing `Join` on your thread, it doesn't actually make much difference, but if you really want you could use `Task.Run` then wait on it

Comment: @Charlieface A small notice: I would add `Enabled = false;` and `Enabled = true;` before and after `await User_Login(...)` to prevent reentrancy.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying ```Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'object' ``` at the ```ExecuteScalarAsync()```

Comment: Ah sorry, you should compare to `null` instead, fixed now